# Is date/time part of SQL Server's datetimeoffset UTC or local?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, timezone

According to Microsoft's page on the `datetimeoffset` data type (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)):

> A time zone offset specifies the zone offset from UTC for a time or datetime value.

But nowhere does it say whether the datetime part of the `datetimeoffset` string literal format is showing either:

- UTC time, with the timezone offset being what to apply to that time to get to localtime, or;
- localtime, with the timezone offset being what to apply to that time to get back to UTC.

This is the string literal format for datetimeoffset: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] [{+|-}hh:mm]`.

My question therefore is, is the `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]` bit of that string literal in localtime or in UTC?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the date represented by your `datetimeoffset` variable is **in your own timezone** (not UTC). `datetimeoffset` just also includes the information about **which** timezone that is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The YYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] [{+|-}hh:mm] format is an ISO8601 format. The [ISO page](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/date_and_time_format.htm) gives

> Coordinated universal time (UTC)
>   Local time with offset to UTC

As this format has the offset then the base time is local. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for other examples.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know.  BTW, the `ISO page` link you showed is broken. :)